# How do I fix my DateTime to show correct answer?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a compare to work but I cant really get it to work correct. I want a simple way to do it but I Think mine is very way is not the best one.

**Fx**

> Time now 2015-01-28 14:58
>
> DepatureTime 2015-01-28 14:59
>
> The answer would be: +1min

**or**

> Time now 2015-01-28 14:59
>
> DepatureTime 2015-01-28 14:59
>
> The answer would be: Now

**or**

> Time now 2015-01-28 14:59
>
> DepatureTime 2015-01-28 15:00
>
> The answer would be: Gone

I have done this so far but it is far from right. The first thing is that I need to get the seconds away from DateTime.

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
var t2 = DateTime.Parse("2015-01-28 15:14");
           
if(t2 < t1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Gone");
}
else if (t2 == t1)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Now");
}
else
     Console.WriteLine("+1");
```

Comment: Use subtraction? `(t2-t1).TotalSeconds`.  What are you asking exactly?

Comment: You can subtract datetime objects to get a time span https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If the format you want to parse is fixed, it's usually a good idea to pass a fixed culture to `DateTime.Parse`.

Comment: See RvdK's answer, especially the part that DateTimes have milliseconds.  Also note that your t1.Kind would be Local whereas t2.Kind is Unspecified.  It doesn't matter in your small example, but could cause issues with other applications.

Answer (score 5):

Some tips:
`t2 == t1` means it has to be exactly the same time (also same milliseconds). You probably only want to compare the year, month, day, hour and minute.

If you do a substraction of 2 `DateTimes` you will get a `TimeSpan`. This `TimeSpan` shows how many minutes they differ from each other.

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse("2015-01-28 15:14");
TimeSpan difference = t2 - t1;
Console.WriteLine("Difference {}".format(difference.TotalMinutes))
```

Note that the `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` is a `double`. So you may want to round it to a whole number inorder to show it to the user.

```
minutes_difference = Math.Round(difference.TotalMinutes, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeOffset t1 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset t2 = DateTime.Parse("2015-01-28 15:14"); // implicit conversion

/* Use the differences as you wish.  E.g.,
          (t1 - t2).Hours 
          (t1 - t2).Minutes
 */
```